# CakePHP assocations deeper level in 2x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have multiple tables associated with each other model names are below:

1. Menu
2. SubMenu
3. Option

SubMenu has the `menu_id`,

Option has the `submenu_id`

I want to show Menu>SubMenu>Option.

How can I do that 3 level association?

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to use the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior.

I understand that your relationships are already defined in the Model classes.

In your `MenuControllers` action, add

```
    $this->Menu->contain(array(
        'SubMenu'=>array(
            'Option'
        )
    ));
```

just before

```
$menus=$this->Menu->find();
```

Don't forget to load the behavior in the Model:

```
class Menu extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Or by calling in your action:

```
$this->Menu->Behaviors->load('Containable');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set up correct associations in models. In `Menu` model (I assume you have correct foreign keys set up):

```
public $hasMany = array('SubMenu');
```

in `SubMenu`:

```
public $hasMany = array('Option');
public $belongsTo= array('Menu');
```

in `Option` model:

```
public $belongsTo= array('SubMenu');
```

And then you can do this(in model):

```
$this->find(...);
```

Use `Containable` and limit to fields you want to use.

More on [model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#associations-linking-models-together).

Answer (score 0):

$this->Menu->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('submenu' =>array( 'className'=> 'submenu',  'foreignKey' => 'menu_id'))));
$this->submenu->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('option' =>array('className' => 'option','foreignKey' => 'submenu_id'))));  '